# Last drawn line on Canvas is solid?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've run into a rather unusual bug. I'm drawing various lines onto a `HTMLCanvasElement` with the following:

```
export const drawLine = (
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
  moveTo: Cartesian2DCoordinate,
  lineTo: Cartesian2DCoordinate,
  lineWidth: number,
  strokeStyle: string
): CanvasRenderingContext2D => {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(moveTo.x, moveTo.y)
  ctx.lineTo(lineTo.x, lineTo.y)
  ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke()
  return ctx
}
```

However, when drawing multiple lines to the Canvas, so looping with something akin to this:

```
for (const line of lines) {
  drawLine(
    ctx, 
    line.moveTo, 
    line.lineTo,
    1, 
    '#A5B4FC80'
  )
}
```

I'm experiencing the ***last*** drawn line is solid...and I'm not sure why this is, some examples below:

[image]
[image]

Has anyone encountered such a bug? What exactly have I done wrong here...

Comment: Could you please add a [mre]?

Comment: Are you sure that's not just a coincidence and you're not just seeing pixel aliasing for lines at certain angles? What if you draw the shape in reverse?

Comment: No, I have actually got some rotation functionality to the canvas, and it seems to just be between those two points.

Comment: @isherwood It's weird, because it's only started happening since I have added three new points. I can see what the issue with those points is tho.

Comment: Why not drop in a list of lines and make a functioning snippet?

Comment: @isherwood I wish I could, there are some astrometric calculations in between the original lines and the ones rendered in the above images - these calculations fully unit tested to work - it only seems to be this one line out of 1000s...and it is *ALWAYS* the last line.

Comment: I've heard the issue can be due to calling ctx.closePath() -> But I have not called that anywhere in my code...

Comment: I've fixed this issue by calling an extra `ctx.beginPath()` and `ctx.closePath()`.